# Using gstreamer to stream from Framebufferr via RTSP

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, framebuffer

I have built GStreamer, GStreamer RTSP Server and some related plugins running streaming via RTSP. GStreamer RTSP Server examples can use some sources from webcam (dev/video0) with v4l2src, videotestsrc, or .MP4 file with filesrc.

So, how can I stream from framebuffer source (dev/fb0) via RTSP?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab framebuffers with GStreamer.

Here is an example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v multifilesrc location=/dev/fb0 ! videoparse format=29 width=1680 height=1080 framerate=30/1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

You then have to adapt it to your RTSP application.

Answer (score 0):

I type the Command in /gst-rtsp-server/example:

> sudo ./test-launch "( multifilesrc location=/dev/fb0 ! videoparse format=29  framerate=30/1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"

But, I got the error:

> stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test 
>   x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:4:4

Using VLC view

> vlc vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test

It's only black screen

Framebuffer info:

> mode "1280x720" 
>       geometry 1280 720 1280 720 32 
>       timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
>       rgba 8/0,8/8,8/16,8/24 
>   endmode